# MeteorJS Mup - Pushing to bundle stuck at 0% on new computer

Tags: meteor, mup

I have a MeteorJS app pushing to a Digital Ocean droplet. I recently got a newer Macbook Pro and am now doing all my dev on that (my old computer was a Macbook Pro too).

When I deploy to Digital Ocean using Mup on my new computer, everything goes as expected but then hangs on 0% when attempting to push the bundle to the server.

I have tried rerunning `mup init` and `mup setup` which works fine with no issues, so it is not an SSH access issue. I can also ssh into my server from my new computer without issue.

I have tried `mup deploy --verbose`, viewed both `Debug=* mup deploy` and `mup logs` but there is no error appearing - it simply hangs at 0% and never fails.

The really odd thing is that when I copy the meteor directory to my old computer and deploy, it works completely fine and does not hang.

Comment: My first guess would be something to do with ssh-keys/config. I don't know what mup uses for copying the bundle, but I would guess it is either `scp` or `rsync`. Can you try `scp`ing a test file over to the server from your new machine and see whether that works?

Comment: If there is no issue on the server, maybe it's one with your build? Can you try `meteor build` to verify your build is basically working?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I am using a password for ssh, not a key pair. Will this make a different?

Comment: @Jankapunkt the build works fine on both machines

Comment: @NateSturcke have you entered your password in the mup.js config? I've never used mup that way, always used a key.

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes have got the password in mup.js. It the same mup file i am using on both computers, so it not a mup config issue. I thought it may be a known_hosts issue, so I ssh into my server, accepted the warning added the server to known_hosts, but no luck.

Comment: and have you tried `scp` and `rsync` manually, to make sure those work, too?

Comment: Yes, have just confirmed both scp and rsync successfully copy a file from the local machine to the server. This makes no sense!!!

Comment: I also tried creating a new test droplet and MUP still hangs at pushing bundle to server - never moving past 0%.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with `node version v21.3.0` and i switched back to  current LTS `v20.9.0` and it is fixed now. It is always a good idea to stick with LTS.

For people who are using mac here is an easy way to change node versions

1- `brew install nvm`

2- `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

3- `nvm install v20.9.0`

4- `nvm use 20.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

At https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/1183 recommend to downgrade Node to v12.18.3.

I was having the same issue and it has worked for me.

I ended uninstalling brew node and using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead.

Comment: Can confirm this has fixed it for me! Well done and thank you so much. In hindsight (like most things), it makes sense given one of the only different things between the computers was the Node version (having only just installed Node on the new computer on setup).